# What is wrong with this XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Given that the path `/XML/Staff/Content/ContentXML/StaffProfile/Role` is correct, and that I have 5 `/XML/Staff` with only one Staff member with the Role of "Partner"

Why does this match all 5 staff members?

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/XML/Staff[Content/ContentXML/StaffProfile/Role='Partner']" mode="List"/>
```

Comment: Is role an attribute or an element?

Comment: Then you need to do `/text()` to select only the text node of `Role`, since the element `Role` itself isn't equal to the string `'Partner'`; as I've answered below.

Comment: It is impossible to uniquely and precisely identify the problem unless you provide the XML document. Please edit the question and provide this missing and important information.

Comment: Okay, this was a mistake by me as there was only one /XML/Staff element. So the test needed to be on the next level. If i'd added the full XML this would have been spotted. Sorry about that. I'd delete this if I could, but it's got answers now.

Comment: John, you can provide your own answer and (after a couple of days) mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen your XML (which you should post for completeness), but I assume `Role` is an XML element and if that's the case, comparing it to a string won't work. Try this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
    select="/XML/Staff[Content/ContentXML/StaffProfile/Role/text()='Partner']"
    mode="List" />
```

If `Role` is an attribute, you need to do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
    select="/XML/Staff[Content/ContentXML/StaffProfile/@Role='Partner']"
    mode="List" />
```

Comment: Was testing this at http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx and when I came back the answer was waiting :)

Comment: Thanks guys! I've been away from XML for a year so text() slipped my mind completly! I'll confirm in the morning and accept :)

Comment: Hi guys, so this was a mistake by me. The Staff element was singular, the plurals are "Content" inside the staff list template it had a match on "Content" which is were I put the test and it works. I didn't need to do the text() function it worked with out that.